# I have started a training Cascade but it is VERY slow... is swap memory the issue?

Tags: opencv, training-data, haar-classifier

I have started training a cascade with ~600 negative images and ~120 positives (distorted and transformed to make ~1500 positive). I am using opencv_traincascade and I have set the parameters as such:

```
numPos: 1000
numNeg: 609
numStages: 20
preCalcValBufSize: 4096 (mb)
preCalcIdxBufSize: 4096 (mb)
stageType: BOOST
featureType: Haar
sampleWidth: 80
sampleHeight: 80
maxFalseAlarmRate: 0.5
weightTrimRate: 0.95
maxDepth: 1
maxWeakCount: 100
mode: All
```

My computer is a mac mini with 16 GB of memory and it is running a quad core i7. It also has a hardrive not SSD. It has been running for about 1 Day 8 hours and it is on training stage 3.

I am wondering if there's any reason that the training is taking so long. At this rate it will take 6-7 days for the training to complete. One thing that I have noticed is that I am typically using 1-2 GB of swap memory and it occasionally says there is "pressure" on my memory. I don't know much about swap memory but I think it might be slowing my training down. How does this work? Also should I restart the training lowering to my memory usage to 2048 mb for both Buf size for the sake of time?

Comment: compare to http://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html : "This is going to take a lot of time. And I don’t mean the old “get a coffee and come back”-taking-a-lot-of-time, no. Running this took a couple of days on my mid-2011 MacBook Air. It will also use a lot of memory and CPU. Do something else while this runs and come back after you noticed that it finished. Even better: use a EC2 box to run this on."

Comment: They cite a ~2 day run while this is a predicted 7 days, with roughly the same amount of images

Answer (score 0):

I know i'm late, but maybe someone will still need answer for this question.
Most likely your problem is using quite big images - i remember running some training (and i took about a the or two) with sampleWidth and sampleHeight set to 20. In the article mentioned above width is 80 and height is 40, but the number of samples is much smaller and the shape of object is quite simple.
The parameters you mentioned (preCalcValBufSize and preCalcIdxBufSize) sets maximum ram usage - so it's like saying "you can use x MB of my ram for preCalcValBufSize and y mb for preCalcIdxBufSize and don't even look at the rest of my memory - i need this for something else." As long as `preCalcValBufSize + preCalcIdxBufSize < avaible ram size` there is no need to use swap (so OS will not use it).